# solr: multiply score with a field

Tags: sorting, solr

Hopefully an easy question: I have added some docs to the index, where every doc has a field `prio`, which is an integer between 1 and 5. There is also a text field for fulltext search.

What I want: multiply the prio-value with the score value and order the docs by that result.

what I tried: this and that :) last thing was `q=whatever _val_:"product(prio, score)"` which didn't work (unknown field `score`)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
q={!boost b=field(prio)}whatever
```

References: [field](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#field), [BoostQParserPlugin](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/search/BoostQParserPlugin.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that before too, but reading the docs again (and again) I found my error: The prio field was stored but not indexed -> score was always 0.0. Thanks again..

Comment: Update: it's called `field` now. i.e. `q={!boost b=field(prio)}whatever`

Comment: Works for me, great! But I don't understand why. I don't find anything about `!boost b=...` in the Reference Guide of Solr 8.x or 9.x. Could you give some more explanation about what is going on exactly? The links you provided are not valid anymore.

Comment: And also how this could be done using SolrNet?

Comment: @TOG see https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Querying.md#localparams

Comment: @MauricioScheffer Thank you for your response regarding who this can be done with SolrNet. Do you also know where the `!boost b=...` Solr syntax is documented?